# Table-Valued Parameter without using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2016

It seems all I can find online are examples of table-valued parameters that require using a stored procedure. I recall doing this in the past without the stored procedure. Is that possible?

This code keeps throwing an error about the type not being specified.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
        UPDATE t1
        SET t1.ScheduledStartUTC = t2.ScheduledStartUTC
        FROM ScheduleTickets AS t1
            INNER JOIN @SetScheduledStart AS t2 ON t1.ScheduleId = t2.ScheduleId AND t1.PatchSessionId  = t2.PatchSessionId 
    ", c);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SetScheduledStart", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = SetScheduleTicketsDateDT;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: That's because you're also required to set the `TypeName` property if you're using `SqlDbType.Structured` for TVPs. (And you cannot get around creating this type first, if that's what you're going for.)

Comment: Ok, I found how to specify the TypeName:  cmd.Parameters["@SetScheduledStart"].TypeName = "dbo.tvpUpdateScheduledStart";

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find how to use it without stored procedure: [Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Parameterized SQL Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#passing-a-table-valued-parameter-to-a-parameterized-sql-statement)

Basically, it requires you to:

1. `CREATE TYPE dbo.tvpUpdateScheduledStart AS TABLE (ScheduleId int, PatchSessionId int)` on the server beforehand.
2. Specify this type in `TypeName` property of a `SqlParameter`.